# Python: Compute the average of a big numbet of arrays without saving them

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, average

I have a huge number of lists and I want to compute the average without storing all of them. Is there any python implementation to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: yes. But you have to show us some of your code.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your situation? Without storing all the averages, or all the lists? Aren't the lists already in memory?

Comment: Try using statistics.mean() with an iterator as parameter. Iterators don't store data, data is called on demand.

Comment: I mean without storing the lists, the lists are computed on the fly. I don't have to keep them all in memory

Comment: just do a running sum and also count and in the end divide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to average entire arrays (must be compatible shapes):

```
running_sum = None
count = 0
for a in yourarraysource:
    if running_sum is None:
        running_sum = a
    else:
        running_sum = running_sum + a
    count += 1
average = running_sum / count
```

If you want to average all elements:

```
running_sum = 0
count = 0
for a in yourarraysource:
    running_sum += a.sum()
    count += a.size
average = running_sum / count
```